# Do you know who stole the diamond?

Tags: knowledge, situation

> One day, a diamond was stolen. Detectives came to the scene and asked
> the owner of the diamond to tell what happened. He said: "Five people
> came to see the gems today. Before they entered the diamond room, my
> secretary brought them five glasses of wine and ice. When we entered
> the diamond room, the diamonds were gone. Before that, there was a
> lady named Alice who looked at the gem." The detective thought about it
> and came up with the answer.

Tips:

> I = D, D = I

Do you know who stole the diamond?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Correct Solution

Could it be

> The secretary?

> The secretary may have brought wine with ice for most of the guests but wine with the diamond for one of the other guests.

The hint meant that

> Ice=Diamond

---

### First Solution (Wrong)

Could it be that

> The owner lied to the detective and just put the diamond elsewhere?

This is because

> The owner seemingly did not provide enough information for the detective to deduce anything about the five people (not even Alice), but also tried to blame it on a person named Alice.

---

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sorry this answer is wrong

Comment: @MyCar Please check my second solution. Thanks!

Comment: The secretary is not Alice, they are different people

Comment: The answer is the secretary, but for the wrong reason

Comment: @MyCar Ok, I just assumed that it was a red herring in wording. I'll keep trying, but can we move this to the chat link I posted to your question about family relations? Thanks.

Comment: I'm in the chat room

Comment: Cheese Cake are you in the chat room?